# Is one type of food better than another for breeding animals?

Tags: junk-jack-x

The three cows in my pen are eating me out of house and home. I cannot keep up with their demands of wheat! Is there a more long-lasting food I can give them? What about for the other livestock?

Answer (score 1):

They also eat leaves which are not too hard to obtain.

Source: [Junk Jack Wiki](http://wiki.pixbits.com/wiki/O-Stuff_Animals_Eat)